# mvn eclipse:eclipse : Adding integration sources

Tags: eclipse, maven, testing, integration

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` automagically has always added `src/test/java` and `src/main/java` to my Eclipse projects, however, it doesn't appear to do the same with `src/integration-test/java`.

How can I get it to also add in my integration tests to my Eclipse project?